# Will refreshing Synchronized Data Extension filter contacts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, data-synchronization

I want to turn on a filter for SDEs in records collection using a boolean field on the object. And then remove all records already in the SDE who do not meet criteria.

Can I simply refresh the SDE to remove these records? Or do I need to unsync the object and then re-sync it within Data stream?

Comment: its not possible to remove records from SDE  you can filter on SDE based on boolean field then you can refresh the filter DE

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a new filter to the sync it will remove contacts from the Sync DE but it will not remove contacts from your account. You will then need to leverage the ['Contact Delete'](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5) process to remove them from the account

I would recommend using a query activity to identify the contacts you plan on filtering out before you change you sync settings. Then use this DE in the delete process. This help article ['Permanently remove Contacts or Subscribers and associated data from Contact Builder'](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000271352&language=en_US&type=1) will also assist.